# Memory leak from UIImage in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have potential memory leak problem from the UIImage objects. Code is as below. Please help.

```
UIImage *image = nil;

if (x == 0) {
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cg1];
} else {
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cg2];
}

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[image release];
```

I tried to release UIImage object after if-else block, but Xcode warned about "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller",

If I remove the [image release], it shows "Potential leak of an object allocated on line ...".

How to solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = nil;

if (x == 0) {
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cg1];
} else {
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cg2];
}

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
// Some code
[imageView release];
```

You take ownership of the object `imageView` and not `image`. So u should release `imageView` and not `image`. Take a look at [Object ownership in Apple's Memory Management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Warning still shown - Potential leak of an object allocated on line ...

Comment: How to investigate ? I tried using Instruments, but I don't really know to use it to check leaks.

Comment: When u use Build and Analyze, u will get a blue icon showing the leak. Click on it to show the leak

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `[UIImage new]` is the same as `[[UIImage alloc] init]`, so you already have an retained instance. Then you throw the pointer to the instance away by calling `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]`, which returns an autoreleased instance that you don't need to retain!

The solution is throwing the `[UIImage new]` out of your code, as well as the `[image release]` at the end.

Comment: Yes, you need to throw out the [image release] too, because the image is already autoreleased.

Comment: Thanks, but after I removed the [image release], it shows "Potential leak of an object allocated on line ...". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating a new instance of a `UIImage` object using the `new` method and assigning it to the `image` variable. Then you are immediately leaking that instance by assigning a different instance to the variable using the `imageWithCGImage:` method.

You don't need to do `UIImage *image = [UIImage new];` at the beginning. You can simply declare your variable without assigning any instances to it. Good practice would be to assign `nil` to it initially.

When you do this you won't need to release the image object later because `imageWithCGImage` returns an autoreleased object.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Warning still shown - Potential leak of an object allocated on line ... Any idea to solve ?